# OpenAM weblogic Policy Agent Installation

Tags: weblogic11g, openam

I have installed Weblogic Policy Agent in OpenAM. Followed the URL “http://openam.forgerock.org/openam-documentation/openam-doc-source/doc/agent-install-guide/index/chap-weblogic.html” to install the policy Agent.
I am using Oracle Weblogic server 10.3.5.0 to use deploy the .war file. Same Weblogic server used for Oracle Identity Manager 11.1.1.5.0. 
In Weblogic Policy Agent post-installation steps need to select Agent Authenticator for the security Realm.

I have doubt here. Whether i want to create the "new realm" or i can use the existing realm "myrealm"? But , "myrealm" is consists the details of OIM.

I am thinking to create the new realm for openAM Weblogic policy Agent, if so what are the things i need to do create new realm for OpenAM.

Please suggest on this.

Thanks & Regards,
Karthick

Answer (score 0):

I am also using openAM on weblogic 10.3.5. I just added the new authenticator to myrealm and set it as optional. My existing authenticator was not OIM but an ldap authenticator.